How to use EC2 placement group using Karpenter auto scaler in AWS
We are using Karpenter for node auto scaling in EKS. To improve the network performance and to achieve the low latency, we are planning to use the placement groups for EC2 instances.
However, after googling, it seems, Karpentger does not support placement group
Environment details:

EKS: 1.30 version

terragrunt version v0.68.14

Terraform v1.9.8


I see this github link
Haz anyone used placement group with Karoenter?
